# CGAL 4.7: Arrangement insert(arr,begin,end) crashes

Tags: cgal

I'm trying to do the aggregate insertion of x-monotone polylines, but I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CGAL::Precondition_exception'
  what():  CGAL ERROR: precondition violation!
Expr: i != INVALID_INDEX
File: /home/vladimir/lib-cgal/include/CGAL/Arr_polycurve_basic_traits_2.h
Line: 727
```

And have no clue why it happens. Do I miss something? Is my input wrong? Or is it a bug? Here is a code snippet resulting in this behavior:

```
#include <vector>

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_segment_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_polyline_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arrangement_2.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel   Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2                                     Point_2;
typedef CGAL::Arr_segment_traits_2<Kernel>                  Segment_traits_2;
typedef CGAL::Arr_polyline_traits_2<Segment_traits_2>       Geom_traits_2;
typedef CGAL::Arrangement_2<Geom_traits_2>                  Arrangement_2;

int main()
{
    Arrangement_2 arr;
    std::vector<Geom_traits_2::X_monotone_curve_2> segments;

    {
        auto ctor = arr.geometry_traits()->construct_x_monotone_curve_2_object();

        typedef std::vector<Point_2> Line;
        std::vector<Line> lines = {
            {{0,0}, {8,0}},
            {{2,0}, {7,0}},
            {{4,2}, {6,3}},
            {{1,1}, {3,0}, {5,0}},
        };

        for (auto &line: lines) {
            segments.push_back(ctor(line.begin(), line.end()));
        }
    }

    insert(arr, segments.begin(), segments.end());

    return 0;
}
```

CGAL version I'm using is 4.7, but I have tried it with 4.5.2 and the lates git version (81d638341) with the same result.

The lines are intersecting, but that should be fine as I understand. I have observed that changing `{{1,1}, {3,0}, {5,0}}` to `{{2,1}, {3,0}, {5,0}}` results in no error. And splitting `{{1,1}, {3,0}, {5,0}}` into two segments `{{1,1}, {3,0}}, {{3,0}, {5,0}}` results in no error as well.

I have also noticed another thread ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224960/cgal-4-4-arrangement-insertarr-curve-crashes-with-some-curves)) with similar problem which was fixed, but I don't see this fix in the version 4.7. Probably it's fixed somewhere else in the code, or perhaps this fix got lost somehow.? Anyway, it looks like it's not related to my problem, but one never knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem and at first glance it looks like a bug. We are looking into it, but for now you have 2 options to work around the problem:
1. Use incremental insertion. The incremental insertion is based on a completely different algorithm.
2. Break each polyline into segments and construct an arrangement of segments instead of an arrangement of polylines. I've tested it with the minimal example that produces the problem you provided (that you, by the way for that) and it works fine.

BW, the link you mentioned is unrelated.